# How to accept number and not prompt for another 4 digit code even if number is below 10000

Tags: python

This is where the Issue happens. Even if the pin is under 4 digits(10000) the second pin input will still run.

```py
print("Hello")
print('Please type your username')
username = input('Place Here:')
print('Please type your secure 4 digit pin for our system')
pin = int(input('Place Here:'))
if pin >= 10000:
   print("Sorry, I didn't understand that. Please try again. 4 digits only")
pin=int(input('Place Here:'))
print('Please provide your name under your registered account')
name = input('Place Here:')
print('Welcome', name, 'you are now logged into White Rock')
print('If you are interested in seeing your username or pin, please type Yes, or No')
question = input("Pace yes or no here:")
if question =='Yes' or question == 'yes':
    print(username)
    print(pin)
elif question == 'No' or question =='no':
    print('Not needed, ok.')
```

Comment: Can you please fix your indentation? I was not able to recover it when fixing the formatting in your post.

Comment: Please sort out the insets so that the code is readable.

Comment: Yes sorry, very new to this. Will fix it now. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](//stackoverflow.com/q/23294658/843953)

Comment: Yes thanks so much. That works perfect!

Comment: My pin is 0000 - this is not possible here?

Comment: `if len(pin) == 4 and pin.isdigit():`

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
if len(str(pin)) !=  4:
```

instead of:

```
 if pin >= 10000:
```

... you may still make this in a little loop and abort after x invalid attempts.

Comment: How about don't convert the input to int in the first place? `pin = input(...)` and then `len(pin)` instead of `pin = int(input(...))` and then `len(str(pin))`